# Сбиваются url() в css файлах после конкатенации

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

**Ситуация**

1. Использую `bower`.
2. В .bowerrc прописал директорию `"vendor/assets/bower_components"`.
3. В конифге application.rb прописал `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')`.
4. Я установил плагин `fotorama`.
5. Все файлы фоторамы теперь лежат здесь `"/vendor/assets/bower_components/fotorama"`.
6. Затем добавил в `application.css` строку `*= require fotorama/fotorama.css` (я и в application.js что нужно добавил, но это здесь не важно).
7. В файле layout'а, я прописал `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>`.

Запускаю сервер `rails server` — всё работает просто идеально. Файл с css вставился таким образом `<link href="/assets/fotorama/fotorama.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />`, внутри этого файла есть строчка: `.fotorama__video-play {background: url(fotorama.png) no-repeat}`, и действительно, файл `fotorama.png` лежит рядышком с файлом css, указанном в теге `<link>`. Отрубаю сервер, перекомпилирую все ассеты `rake assets:precompile` и запускаю сервер в продакшн моде `rails server -e production`.

**Проблема**

В продакшн моде все css сливают в один большой файл, он выглядит так: `<link href="/assets/application-2d31fc33890d01b046194920367eb3d4.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />`, в нём по-прежнему есть строчка `.fotorama__video-play {background: url(fotorama.png) no-repeat}`, ну, в общем, из-за неё браузер пытается найти файл с картинкой здесь: `http://localhost:3000/assets/fotorama.png`, а его там нет, честно признаться, его вообще нигде теперь нет.

**Вопросы:**

1. Почему картинки из папки `/vendor/assets/bower_components` не перелетели в папку `public/assets`?
2. Чтобы такого придумать, чтобы всё заработало, при условии: не менять содержимое файла fotorama.css руками (програмно я согласен), потому что не комильфо руками лезть в вендорные пакеты?

*Я уже долго не могу справиться с этой проблемой, буду признателен любым попыткам помочь мне.
Спасибо.*

Answer (score 1):

Эй, есть офигенный гем `bower-rails`. Ставишь, пишешь зависимости в `Bowerfile`, делаешь `rake bower:install`. Все проблемы с ассетами сразу устраняются.

Comment: Я рассматривал его как вариант, но у меня есть необходимость иногда переопределять свойство "main" указанное в конфиге отдельного плагина "main", путём внесения этого нового "main" в свойство "overrides" в файле bower.json. Чтобы потом мой gulpfile отобрал только то что мне нужно с помощью модуля "Main Bower Files". Реально ли сделать что-то такое с помощью gem 'bower-rails'?

Comment: Нет, не знаю, чем вам помочь.

Comment: Я нашел достойное решение. Но у меня не хватает репутации, чтобы выложить его в качестве ответа. По-этому если кратко то так: 1. Создаю задачу для gulp: если видишь изменение в файле bower.json, с помощью npm модуля main-bower-files собери все файлы прописанные в main для каждого из установленных в bower плагинов. Составь файл манифест из путей к css файлам и файл манифест из js файлов (для css `"app/assets/stylesheets/bower_components_manifest.css"`). 2. Задача для gulp: если видишь изменения в файле `"bower.json"`, собери все css файлы, пройдись по ним, и с помощью npm модуля...

Comment: ...и с помощью модуля gulp-css-url-adjuster поставь перед каждым относительным url в каждом css файле эту строку `<%= asset_path '`, и после каждого url поставь строку `' %>`. 3. в файле `"app/assets/stylesheets/application.css"` прописываю `"require bower_components_manifest"`. 4. Чтобы картинки и остальные файлы перекидывались из папки `"/vendor/assets/bower_components"` в папку `"public/assets"`, нужно прописать в конфиге `"application.rb"` вот эту строку `"config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)"`, потому что по умолчанию перекидываются только файлы из папки "app/assets".

Comment: Забыл написать. Еще к каждому css файлу при внесении туда изменений в url'ы, нужно добавить не только руби код но и путь к файлу. Таким образом `url("fotorama.png")` >> `url("<%= asset_path 'fotorama/fotorama.png' %>")`, также к каждому файйлу нужно расширение ".erb"